# Socket programming to connect android with a laptop

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am developing an app where I should be able to remotely access laptop camera's using my app. But how do I write a socket programming as I am new to android, I don't know if by just using Java socket programming is it possible to access laptop cameras

Answer (score 1):

There is a Socket class and a ServerSocket class in Java. You give both of the clients sockets and have them connect to the ServerSocket. If you're remotely connecting to the laptop from your Android device from a different network, then you may need to set up a server to host the ServerSocket part on. Google App Engine can help with that. It also lets you deploy your Java app directly to the app engine via a plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: I know how to code Socket class and ServerSocket class in Java. But the later part that you told me regarding google App engine I am unaware of it. And I have a server setup that is up and running @TreeHouseFalcon

Comment: Go here to get started with GAE: https://console.cloud.google.com/

Comment: @TreeHouseFalcon if i want to connect between hosts between different network can i achieve that only with the link you provide?

Comment: Yes. GAE will provide you with a URL that your web app is on. There are doGet and doPost methods in the main class. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a **simple tcp server-client** application, as soon as both devices are on the same network is going to work like charm...

- on the Android:

  The client which must search and find the server (in this case the pc)
- on the PC:
   a server client waiting for the android (actually waiting for a tcp client)

---

As soon as both connect, send some formatted string that will be predefined by you and interpreted by the server as Commands...

with those commands try to turn-off/on the camera, disconnect the app, take a picture etc etc

if you look properly you will find 10000 of examples of java tcp server clients...

good luck!

Comment: Thanks.. but could you tell me if this is possible or not. I have a server right now. And I at this moment I can access the client (laptop's) IP address as I have deployed and PhP file in server. Now I will validate if the user behind the laptop and android is same by asking him the pin which will be given to him. If validation is sucessful then I will access the laptops Camera using my android app.
But where what programs must be written is confusing to me. And also tell me if what I have planned will work or not ?